# Prove $\frac{e^{px} -1}{x}$ is integrable over $(0,1)$

Tags: integration

Prove $$\frac{e^{px} -1}{x}$$ is integrable over $(0,1)$.

Trying to use a form of the monotone convergence theorem, but not getting anywhere.

Comment: The function is continuous, hence Riemann/Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: I agree with Prahlad's comment if we agree the function be defined as $p$ at $x=0$, which via LHopital is the limit there.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Monotone convergence theorem!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: Define the extension 
$$
f(x)  = \begin{cases}
\frac{e^{px}-1}{x} & x \in (0,1] \\
p & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
and note that $\lim_{x \to 0} (e^{px}-1)/x = \frac{d}{dx}\big|_{x=0} e^{px} = p$ so that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Now, what can you say about the integrability of $f$ and why can you conclude the same for your function?